# Deleting a question which is answered and must be deleted for company reasons

Tags: support, questions, specific-question, account-suspension, vote-to-delete

I want to delete my question which is answered.

I breached my company policy by sharing the original code! Now my account is  suspended for 2 days! How do I delete an answered questions?

Comment: That question doesn't tell what to do when a user is suspended. (Not sure if there is a difference btw)

Comment: You'll need to wait 2 days and flag a moderator. If it's a serious issue, eg detrimental to the company in a large way like you work for Google and posted core code (unlikely of course), then perhaps emailing Stack would be needed. But I imagine 2 days will be fine. Posting things against your company policy *and* being suspended here is probably a warning that things are being done without enough fore-thought.It's probs time to reflect a bit

Answer (score 8):

You need to flag your question. Explain in the custom flag reason why it should be deleted. Since you are not able to flag since you are suspended, you either have to wait, or contact SE directly using the `Contact Us`, at the bottom of this page. (handling of those requests can usually take some days too, so you probably have to wait either way)

A moderator will act as he think he should. Note that by posting it here, you gave it away already, so not sure if he will actually delete it.

By the way, you are suspended in order to cool down. Maybe your current attempts to get your question deleted weren't following the rules. Make sure to stay nice. (indeed... [this editing of you](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/27252579/revisions) isn't very constructive)

Comment: But I need the contents to be deleted  with immediate actions Please let me know directions to get deleted with immediate action

Comment: Then use the `Contact Us` option. It is the only way. Or ping a moderator in chat.

Comment: @jack: Can you post a link to the question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27252579/unable-to-set-property-value-of-undefined-or-null-reference-in-ie11

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26834845/ie11-onreadystatechange-event-is-not-firing

Comment: Please  delete the above two questions.since my account is locked I cannot us contact us or ping a moderator in chat

Comment: I don't think you should worry too much about those questions. There isn't something really company specific. This could be just any sample code.

Comment: @jack edit trolling is not the way to attract moderator attention, at least not positive attention. At best,  you'll end up being banned from suggesting edits. Stop doing it.

Comment: @jack Your edits to your posts on SO caused the ban for sure. You just could have flagged them, and they would have been gone already.

Comment: @Pat actually I was referring to his edit here on this very question, messing with the tags just to "get attention" as the edit summary itself says. Hopefully it was the first and the last. :/

Comment: Thanks for your  immediate attack ! you saved my day ! @ShadowWizard i will follow the same !Also Please edit this question as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27252579/unable-to-set-property-value-of-undefined-or-null-reference-in-ie11

Comment: Got your point! I will follow the rules hereby ! Please modify the below questions as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27252579/unable-to-set-property-value-of-undefined-or-null-reference-in-ie11

Comment: No @jack, I will not. That's not my place, and the contents will still be available to everyone anyway so it's pointless. See my answer for the correct way to handle those things.

Answer (score 5):

If this really breaches your company policy you can file a DMCA notice, asking Stack Exchange to purge (hard delete) the question so that it won't be available even to high rep users and moderators.

Stack Exchange does not have a DMCA form of its own (yet?) but you can follow the steps described [here](http://brainz.org/dmca-takedown-101/):

> ### How to File a Takedown Notice
>
> If you discover that work you hold the copyright in is being infringed and wish to file a DMCA notice. You can take the following steps to do so.
>
> 1. Determine if the work is infringing, consult an attorney if necessary.
> 2. Take screenshots or otherwise preserve the infringing site, useful if a dispute should arise later.
> 3. Obtain a [stock DMCA notice](http://www.plagiarismtoday.com/dmca-contact-information/) template and fill it in with the required information.
> 4. <s>Using a service such as WhoIsHostingThis or Domain Tools, locate the host of the site where the work is located.</s>
> 5. Look on the host's site and attempt to locate the contact information for their DMCA agent.
> 6. Failing that, see if the host has registered with the U.S. Copyright Office and provided the needed information there.
> 7. If that fails, send the notice to the host's abuse team.
> 8. Wait at least 72 hours and ensure that the work has been removed.
> 9. If unable to secure removal of work (IE: Not a U.S.-based host or otherwise uncooperative), consider filing a notice with each of the major search engines.

Steps 4-7 are struck here because they're not relevant, simply email the notice to Stack Exchange itself at `team@stackexchange.com` and it should reach them.

Comment: This could get hazardous if the one posting this is the one actually posting. I wouldn't like the results be send to legal@companyname.com... ;)

Comment: Note that in section #15 of SE's [legal](http://stackexchange.com/legal) page there are details surrounding how to report a copyright violation.

Comment: @Servy: Hmmm "that the material is not authorized by the copyright owner, its agent or law", so the copyright holder should post this... I guess just any employee isn't a copyright holder, so he has to go to management to get this fixed.

Comment: Yeah, @Pat is probably right, it's not the employee place to file that request and it would likely be rejected. Question is how to edit my answer to reflect this...

Comment: @ShadowWizard: `Step 0: Go to your manager and tell him you screwed up`.

Comment: @Servy you're right, I missed that somehow. Will edit my answer to quote that page later, feel free to do so if you want. :)

Comment: IS there way to edit my code instead of deleting it ! I want to edit the code at least for now .

Comment: atleast I want to remove the parameter/change the parameters for this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27252579/unable-to-set-property-value-of-undefined-or-null-reference-in-ie11?noredirect=1#comment42979177_27252579 .Please remove my account suspension This account is temporarily suspended to cool down. The suspension period ends in 2 days.

Comment: @PatrickHofman@ShadowWizard .atleast I want to remove the parameter/change the parameters for this question  .Please remove my account suspension This account is temporarily suspended to cool down. The suspension period ends in 2 day http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27252579/unable-to-set-property-value-of-undefined-or-null-reference-in-ie11?noredirect=1#comment42979177_27252579

Comment: @jack what you mean "change parameters"? What parameters? As for suspension, only a Stack Overflow moderator can do that, neither me nor Patrick are moderators.

Comment: I want my code to replaced as below how do i contact the moderators as i cannot chat and already sent a information from contact us page.

Comment: @ShadowWizard if(typeof returnValue == "undefined") {
        document.getElementById("xxxxxx").value = "cancelled";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("xxx").value = returnValue.interestName;
        document.getElementById("xxxx").value = returnValue.city;
        document.getElementById("xxxx").value = returnValue.state;
        document.getElementById("xxx").value = returnValue.zip;
        document.getElementById("xyxx").value = returnValue.street;
    } postCommand(null, "navigate", "xxxx", "", "");
}

Comment: @jack the first one can't be changed since it's used in the answer. Changing it would also render the answer meaningless. However, the rest are not relevant to the question so I've simply removed them all - hope that's enough.

Comment: @ShadowWizard@Servy . Thanks Please rename the parameters for client sideredirect and useraction http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27252579/unable-to-set-property-value-of-undefined-or-null-reference-in-ie11?noredirect=1#comment42979177_27252579

Comment: @jack you can do it yourself very soon